# JS. Некорректно отображается дата

Tags: javascript

```js
var td = (new Date('2017-05-16 13:45'));

console.log(td); //вывод: 2017-05-16T08:45:00.000Z
console.log(td.getHours()); //вывод: 13
```

Подскажите, почему такой вывод? он выводит по гринвичу время. нахожусь в зоне UTC+5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода даты лучше использовать `toLocaleString`, можно с опциями:

```js
var td = new Date('2017-05-16 13:45');

console.log(td)
console.log(td.toLocaleString())
console.log(td.toLocaleString("ru", {timeZone: 'UTC'}))
console.log(td.toLocaleString("ru", {timeZone: 'Europe/Moscow'}))
console.log(td.toLocaleString("ru", {timeZone: 'Europe/Moscow', era: 'long'}))
```

Список остальных опции можно посмотреть [тут](http://learn.javascript.ru/intl#intl-datetimeformat)